# How to create audio onended event on coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor, babeljs

I am trying to call a function when audio ends in coffeescript, I texted the code in javascript and it work perfectly but not in coffeescript.

Here is the entire code on coffeescript.

```coffee
play: () ->
    if (@getConfig "musicPath") != "../audioclips/backgroundmusics/"
      @pathtoMusic = @getConfig "musicPath"
    else
      @pathtoMusic = path.join(__dirname, @getConfig "musicPath")

    @musicFiles = fs.readdirSync(@pathtoMusic.toString())
    @music = new Audio(@pathtoMusic + @musicFiles[0])
    @music.volume = @getConfig "musicVolume"

    @isPlaying = false if (@music.paused)
    return null if @isPlaying

    @isPlaying = true
    @music.play()
    @music.onended = ->
        @music.play() //-----Here doesn't work------//
```

I am using atom text editor to rum the coffeescript code in a package, and chrome to rum the javascript code.

For be more specific. I saw a package that use the onended event on atom, here is the code.

> code-champion

```
'use babel';

epicVictory() {
      if (this.isPlaying) return
      console.log('Epic Victory!');
      let maxIndex = this.winFiles.length - 1
      let minIndex = 0
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxIndex - minIndex + 1) + minIndex)
      this.audio = new Audio(this.winpath + this.winFiles[randomIndex])

      this.audio.onended = () => {
          this.audio.play() //-------here work-----//
          //this.isPlaying = false
      }

  this.isPlaying = true

  this.audio.volume = this.volume
  this.audio.play()
  return true
},
```

I converted the babel code to javascript using a online converter and I got this.

> babel to javascript

```
//imput
this.music.onended = () => {
    this.audio.play()
}

//ouput
this.music.onended = function () {
    this.music.play();
};
```

Then I converted the javascript code to coffeescript compiler and I got this.

> javascript to coffeescript

```
//imput
this.music.onended = function () {
    this.autoPlay();
}

//ouput
@music.onended = ->
  @music.play()
```

But the code only work on babel. I Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The audio plays normally but do nothing when it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the fat arrow function in coffeescript to bind your "this":

```
@music.onended = =>
 @autoPlay()
```

If you can post a little bit more of the context, that might help.

Comment: No problem! Do you mind marking that as the solution then?